# Jquery - Facebook Like Alert/Popup Box

Tags: jquery, css, facebook

I finally found the perfect popup style box for my facebook application, However it seems to behaving very strangely in IE.
The bottom buttons hang to the right..

You can see it in action here

http://demos.frnzzz.com/popup/

Been messing around with the css for a while but can't put my finger on it..

HTML

```
    <body>
<div id="main">
 <div id="btn">Load Popup</div>
 <div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
 <div id="popupContact">
  <a id="popupContactClose">Close</a>
  <div id="popup_head"><h1>WebSpeaks.in</h1></div>
  <div id="personal">Post to Profile<br><br><br></div>
  <div id="contactArea">
   <textarea id="text"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div id="buttonArea">
   <div class="SharingOptions_Text">
    <a href="#" style="color:#3B5998;">Send as a Message instead</a>
   </div>
   <div id="Sharer_btns">
    <input type="button" value="Share" class="s_btn"/>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" class="c_btn"/>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script language="javascript">
function loadPopup()
{
 $("#backgroundPopup").css({"opacity": "0.1"});
 $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("fast");
 $("#popupContact").slideDown("slow");
}
function disablePopup()
{
 $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
 $("#popupContact").slideUp("slow");
}
function centerPopup()
{
 var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
 var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
 var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
 var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
 $("#popupContact").css({"position": "absolute","top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,"left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2});
 $("#backgroundPopup").css({"height": windowHeight});
}

$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("#btn").click(function()
 {
  centerPopup();
  loadPopup();
 });

 $("#popupContactClose, .c_btn").click(function()
 {
  disablePopup();
 });

 $(document).keypress(function(e)
 {
  if(e.keyCode==27)//Disable popup on pressing `ESC`
  {
   disablePopup();
  }
 });
});
</script>
```

CSS

```
#main{
width:500px;
text-align:center;
margin:100px;
font-family:"lucida grande",tahoma,verdana,arial,sans-serif;
}
#btn{
border:2px solid #00999999;
background-color:#3366FF;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:14px;
width:100px;
height:30px;
}

#popupContact *{
border:0pt none;
margin:0pt;
padding:0pt;
color:#333333;
text-align:left;
}
#popupContact body{
background:#fff none repeat scroll 0%;
line-height:1;
font-size: 12px;
margin:0pt;
height:100%;
}
#popupContact a{
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:10px;
}
#backgroundPopup{
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:100%;
width:100%;
top:0;
left:0;
background:#000000; 
z-index:1;
}
#popupContact{
background-color:#fff;
display:none;
position:fixed;
_position:absolute; /* hack for internet explorer 6*/
height:250px;
width:450px;
border:10px solid #999999;
z-index:2;
-moz-border-radius: 9px;
-webkit-border-radius: 9px;
}
#popupContact h1{ 
background:#6D84B4 none repeat scroll 0 0;
border-color:#3B5998 #3B5998 -moz-use-text-color;
border-style:solid solid none;
border-width:1px 1px medium;
color:#FFFFFF;
font-size:14px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:3px;
margin:0;
}
#popupContactClose{
line-height:14px;
right:6px;
top:4px;
position:absolute;
display:block;
color:#FFFFFF;
}
#personal{
padding:5px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:12px;
}
#popupContact #buttonArea{
background:#F2F2F2;
border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
height:34px;
margin:0px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0px;
width:100%;
padding-top:5px;
}
#contactArea #text{
border:2px solid #cccccc;
margin:5px;
height:50px;
width:95%;
padding:0;
}
#buttonArea .SharingOptions_Text{
padding:3px;
float:left;
}
#buttonArea .SharingOptions_Text a{
color:#3B5998;
font-size:11px;
}
#Sharer_btns{
float:right;
}
#Sharer_btns .s_btn{
margin:2px 6px 6px 5px;
font-size:13px;
background-color:#5B74A8;
background-position:0 -48px;
border-color:#29447E #29447E #1A356E;
color:#FFFFFF;
padding:2px 6px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align:middle;
white-space:nowrap;
}

#Sharer_btns .c_btn{
margin:2px 6px 6px 5px;
border-color:#999999 #999999 #888888;
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
color:#333333;
cursor:pointer;
display:inline-block;
font-size:11px;
font-weight:bold;
padding:2px 6px;
text-align:center;
text-decoration:none;
vertical-align:middle;
white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Any Idea?

Comment: I don't see any problem. Can you specify your problem more concretely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified a bottom position . For IE7 you also need to explicitly specify a left or a right position

```
#popupContact #buttonArea{
    background:#F2F2F2;
    border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;
    height:34px;
    margin:0px;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```